# Как соединить данные таблицы в одну?

Tags: sql, таблицы

[image: Имеется таблица1]

Имеется таблица1 и таблица2 с колонками дата и табель, данные таблицы нужно соединить по этим двум колонкам, как это сделать?

Comment: Использовать JOIN

Comment: как сделать join к именам колонок?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+join+%D0%BA+%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA

Answer (score 1):

1. Если речь идёт о том, чтобы объединить две таблицы в одну, объединив хранение их данных, то нужно создать общую таблицу, потом выбрать данные с обеих и по общим ключам вставить.
2. Если нужно сделать выборку данных, то просто посредством запроса с JOIN.

> SELECT *
>
> FROM t1
>
> JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.number

Так как я не вижу двух таблиц, то привёл лишь шаблон использования такого запроса.